# Npgsql и обработка ошибок подлючения к серверу Postgre SQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, c#-7.3, npgsql

Не работал Npgsql никогда. Со стандартными плагинами для подключения к SQL Server ни когда не испытал проблем. Здесь же в тупике. Делаю самое элементарное - форму авторизации. При нажатии на кнопку, проходит подлкючение. Но как обрабатывать исключения в нем? Т.е. сейчас я не могу разблокировать кнопку после проверки подключение, т.к. получаю "Вызвано исключение: "Npgsql.PostgresException" в mscorlib.dll".

Часть кода:

```
    async Task<bool> CheckConnection()
    {
         using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(MMVar.ConString))
         {
            btn_login.Enabled = false;
            conn.Open();
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("True");

                frm_main f_Main = new frm_main();
                Visible = false;
                f_Main.Visible = true;
                return true; 
            }
            else 
            {
                btn_login.Enabled = true;
                Console.WriteLine("false"); 
                return false; 
            }

         }
    }

    try
    {
        CheckConnection();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        btn_login.Enabled = true;
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
```

Соответвенно, в случаи успеха проблем нет...

Был бы очень признателен, если поправите и так же тыкните меня носом в нужный раздел wiki по npgsql, так как там я ничего не могу толкового обнаружить...

Answer (score 0):

Не на том месте проверяю исключения...
Получил, что хотел.

```
    using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(MMVar.ConString))
    {
        try
        {
            btn_login.Enabled = false;
            conn.Open();
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("True");

                frm_main f_Main = new frm_main();
                Visible = false;
                f_Main.Visible = true;

            }
            else
            {
                btn_login.Enabled = true;
                Console.WriteLine("false");

            }
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
            
            var answer = ex.ToString();

            if (answer.Contains("28P01")) Console.WriteLine("Неверный пароль");
            if (answer.Contains("3D000")) Console.WriteLine("База данных не найдена");
            else Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}");

            btn_login.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Лучше ловить `NpgsqlException`/`PostgresException` и проверять свойство `Code`.

Comment: Оу... Спасибо! Действительно, так удобне) Как и говорил, еще изучать и изучать npgsql....

Comment: Только что выявил недостаток NpgsqlException/PostgresException - при неверно указанном хосте бежит в Open() и не обрабатывает искючение. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: "Этот хост неизвестен" . На ошибку БД и имя/логина работает как надо...